# How to create an error so that GetLastError returns the error?

Tags: c++, windows

I've a function to convert GetLastError function to string to use in my project. But before deploying, I need to test in a sample program. 
When I test it, it gets me no error, because the sample program doesn't have any error.

Can anyone help me how can I generate a couple of errors in std::errc, so that GetLastError throw them?

Comment: May be `SetLastError()` will be useful to you. Also, post your sample program for more help.

Comment: You should be using FormatMessage().  You can call it with any number, it doesn't have to be the one returned by GetLastError().  But yeah, SetLastError() works too.  Better also make sure you fail the test that actually checks if there's an error, broken error checking is a very notorious bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `SetLastError()` from the same thread with desired error code.

Take a look on the SetLastError documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)